# Ubuntu-Desktop-Next has gone. How do I install 64-bit Ubuntu Touch?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, 64-bit

The questions so far on AskUbuntu about Ubuntu Touch on 64-bit x86 machines say to install Ubuntu Desktop Next and then install unity8-lxc.  However Ubuntu Desktop Next appears to have disappeared and all the links now don't work.

If I have a clean 64-bit x86 multitouch tablet, what's the correct way to obtain and install a 64-bit version of Ubuntu Touch for PC now?

Do I:

- Use a special Ubuntu Touch image.  If so, where is it?  (Only 32-bit PC version is currently in http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-touch/daily-preinstalled/current/ )
- Install Ubuntu 15.10 Desktop amd64 and then do `apt-get remove ubuntu-desktop; apt-get install ubuntu-touch`? (Because the ubuntu-touch package has suddenly appeared in the 64-bit repository)
- Compile my own copy?  If so, where?
- Something else?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the 64bit builds of the Ubuntu Touch were not available from the start. I guess that the Desktop Next version was the testing bed before Canonical introduced Unity8 LXC.

For the time being, the following [link](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Unity8inLXC) provides you the necessary info for installing Unity8-LXC if you insist on using 64bit version of Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks.  Well my tablet has 8GB of RAM and then quite a bit of graphical memory, too, so I'm concerned that 32-bit would be a bit of a waste.  Plus, I believe that the proprietary intel firmware is a 64-bit only.

Comment: What are the hardware specs of your tablet?

Comment: I've just found out that there is also Ubuntu-core (has many architectures available) so you could start from [here](http://cdimages.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-core/daily/current/ "Install ubuntu-core")

Comment: It's a Dell Venue 11 Pro 7140 - Intel Core M-5Y71 with 8GB RAM.  From experience, some things didn't work quite right until kernel 4.2.0 and the latest intel-firmware package was installed.

Comment: Lol.  I looked at the instructions to install Ubuntu Core and the thought came to me that I came to Ubuntu to get away from a Gentoo-esque install process. :-p

Comment: That problem is due to new Skylake architecture Intel introduced this year and the problem in known for [some time](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=intel-skl-prelim-support). You could also try to install some more bleeding-edge distro like Fedora (for) and enable community repos for the Intel drivers.

Comment: It seems that there are some issues with Dell Venue 11 Pro 7000 line. Have you tried booting Ubuntu from Live-USB or SD-card?

Comment: Yes, I have Ubuntu Desktop 15.10 working perfectly (apart from an open bug regarding the power button not yet being properly recognised), thank you.   I tried installing Unity8-MIR as an additional desktop environment and can log into it, but none of the applications run at all.

Comment: I picked up another one, so I'm looking to do a proper install of Ubuntu Touch from scratch so that I can discount issues with Ubuntu-Desktop being already installed.  I saw the 32-bit PC edition and thought I could just get an ISO and install it like I do with the Ubuntu Desktop ISO.

Comment: I suppose that kernels (and Ubuntu editions) should be selected according to your hardware: as Touch Edition is intended for smartphone/tablet market, it is exclusively ARM, while Desktop Editions (which I think is your case) is Intel/AMD (which is what you should install and then follow the Instructions for Unity8-LXC install.

Comment: Ubuntu Touch is not exclusively ARM.  There is a PC version of Ubuntu Touch intended for x86 Tablets.  The only issue is that it's only available for 32-bit.  Furthermore, the Desktop edition doesn't work very well on a tablet with no keyboard.  (Layout manager is painful, and the onscreen keyboard is clunky, at best.)

Answer (score 0):

So far the working unity8+MIR is only available on ubuntu-touch running on ARM devices (phones).

They stopped making the desktop-next.isos for PC. So if you want to test that on PC hardware you will need to install a regular ubuntu install and then install one of the unity8 packages. like `unity8-desktop-session-mir` 
but i am not sure how good that will work as a tablet for now.

Comment: I tried this on an existing 15.10 box but ended up with an unusable interface (apps kept closing instantly).  it If what you say is correct, what are the 64-bit ubuntu-touch packages for?

Comment: AFAIK that is for testing/developing purposes right now.
They targeted the Smartphones first with ARM hardware and with running the Android hardware drivers wrapped into a container underneath.

Comment: see this for more informations: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Unity8Desktop